# How does an Okta defined app talks to a custom authorization server

Tags: okta, okta-api

I am trying to learn how to use OKTA as a token issuer for an application.

I am a bit confused as to the connection between a custom authorization server and an Okta application. How do I assign an okta application to the authorization server so it will be able to issue tokens for that application with the applications scopes?

I don't see any api call to do it in the server's api here: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/authorization-servers/

Is it even true that an application needs to be assigned to an authorization server, or is it done in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to assign an application to an authorization server is by using an access policy on the server which defines the app